# Has anyone had success uploading a video or photo to Google Plus from iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, google

I'm looking for any way to post media to google plus using only an iOS device. I am able to get still photos into my linked picasa account, but fail at getting it posted to a circle (or the public) in google plus.

- Still Pictures embedded into the stream is a must have.
- Bonus points if I can control more than one or have a fancy album like posterous handles multiple pictures.
- Video upload would be nice.
  Sound or a combination of all three would be just way too cool.

It's fair game to ask me to sign up for any other sharing service and link accounts (even if I have to use a computer for the setup). Paid apps are fine. Web apps are fine.

I'm not looking for pretty - just something that when posted, will show a thumbnail and look almost like I added the media from the desktop version of google plus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but the app from the store is out and will let you embed media better than the web app can.